# ElasticSearch - Latest record per day per ID from elastic

Tags: sql, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have index in Elsaticsearch of records of form:

```
Record{
  Timestamp;
  Id;
  .
  .}
```

It has multiple records for ID per day.

I want to fetch latest record per Id per day.
Can you please help me with such query?

Example-
Records :

```
R1 -> Id=A1, Timestamp = 2021-02-02_12:00:00, other fields
R2 -> Id=A1, Timestamp = 2021-02-02_11:00:00, other fields
R3 -> Id=A2, Timestamp = 2021-02-02_10:30:00, other fields
R4 -> Id=A2, Timestamp = 2021-02-02_10:00:00, other fields
R5 -> Id=A1, Timestamp = 2021-02-01_13:00:00, other fields
R6 -> Id=A1, Timestamp = 2021-02-01_11:00:00, other fields
R7 -> Id=A2, Timestamp = 2021-02-01_11:30:00, other fields
R8 -> Id=A2, Timestamp = 2021-02-01_10:00:00, other fields
```

Required output:
Complete records : R1, R3, R5, R7

Answer (score 0):

I see two possible ways to do it:

Use using `date_histogram` daily histogram and then `top_hits` agg for each bucket get the latest Id by date:

```json
POST /query_logs/_search?size=0
{
  "aggs": {
    "days": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "timestamp",
        "calendar_interval": "day"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_id": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "sort": [
              {
                "timestamp": "desc"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If your IDs are incremental, you could then use `max` aggregation instead of `top_hits`:

```json
POST /query_logs/_search?size=0
{
  "aggs": {
    "days": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "timestamp",
        "calendar_interval": "day"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_id": {
          "max": {
            "field": "id"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Added example to my question for clarity on requirement.

Comment: So the first query will do. You'll just need to parse the output in your client.

Comment: Doesn't work, Getting multiple records with same ID.